# SharePoint 2016 - Hybrid Search with multiple environments

Tags: search, 2016, hybrid

Is it possible with the SharePoint 2016 Hybrid Search to connect multiple SharePoint 2016 environments (3 for example) environments with 1 Office 365 tenant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the great value propositions for Hybrid Search. Rather than maintain a central farm that crawls (over the WAN) the other farms, you can have each farm crawl independently and push the content to the Cloud Index. When you onboard the farm and configure the connection you just identify the same Tenant for each farm.

Comment: the question specifically talks about SharePoint 2016. How about SharePoint 2013, would the same thing be possible?

Comment: Same for SharePoint 2013. If you also want SharePoint 2010, 2007, File Shares and BCS, all are possible. You have to configure a 2013 or 2016 crawler and direct it at those legacy environments.